# deny access using server ip

Tags: apache, debian

how can i refuse connection when someone try to visit my server ip on browser? am using apache web server, for now am using this conf for server ip

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias www.localhost
     Redirect 403 /
     ErrorDocument 403 " " 
</VirtualHost>
```

but yet user make connection when visiting my server ip on browser and getting "403" but i don't want to make any connection at all, is that possible and in same time keep sites linked to my server ip works?

so if user visit mysiteexample.com there is connection and if server ip doesn't make connection?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need `ServerAlias 1.2.3.4` to have this virtual host match requests to http://1.2.3.4/, assuming it's not the default or only port 80 virtual host.